# Do orientation preserving diffeomorphisms preserve homological intersection?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a $4$- dimensional oriented manifold and let D be a 2-dimensional submanifold. Is it true that any $\phi \in \text{Diff}^+(M)$(the set of orientation preserving diffeomorphisms) preserves homological intersection  i.e  $[D] \cdot [D] = \phi_{*}[D] \cdot \phi_{*}[D]$.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to further know how do you go about showing the claim that $[\phi_{*}(D)] \cdot [\phi_{*}(D)] = \phi_{*}([D] \cdot [D])$?

Comment: Poincare duality is natural for orientation preserving diffeomorphisms, and the intersection product is Poincare dual to the cup product. Alternatively; pick transverse representatives and literally push them forward, and the intersection of the pushed forward cycles will be the pushforward of the intersection.